# A necessary and sufficient condition on a normed space $X$ for the strong operator topology and norm topology on $B(X)$ to coincide

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Is there a simple criterion that determines whether the strong operator topology and norm topology on $B(X)$ coincide, when $X$ is a normed space? If $X$ is a Hilbert space, the necessary and sufficient criterion is for $X$ to be finite-dimensional, which is as simple as it gets.

I've been trying to use Riesz's lemma somehow, but I don't immediately see how it translates into an existence of a sequence of linear operators that converges in SOT but does not converge in the norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finite dimension is alwyas a characterization: Fix $x\in X$ with norm $1$. Then $X^*\to B(X)$, $\varphi \mapsto (y\mapsto \varphi(y)x)$ identifies the dual $X^*$ with a subspace of $B(X)$ such that the operator norm of $B(X)$ induces the dual norm on $X^*$ and the SOT induces the weak$^*$-topology on $X^*$. Moreover, the weak$^*$ topology coincides with the dual norm topology if and only if $X$ is finite dimensional. (There is a weak$^*$-seminorm $p(\varphi)=\max\{|\varphi(x_1)|,\ldots,|\varphi(x_n)|\}$ majorizing the dual norm and by Hahn-Banach this implies that the linear span of $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ is $X$).